# Chrome devtools network tab - websocket message source/initiator

Tags: javascript, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I have a websocket that sends some messages to my server and I would like to find out what code is causing the messages to be send.
I can see the websocket and its messages by opening the chrome devtools, going to the network tab, looking for the request of type `websocket`, clicking on it and going to the tab `messages`. When looking at the requests in the network tab itself, they have a column `Initiator`, which links to the code having initialized the request, the same sadly isn't true for the messages overview.

How can I get the same information for each individual message?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible now in Network panel now. I've created a feature request for the Chrome DevTools team in https://crbug.com/1348694. Please leave additional comment on your use case there.

However, one thing you can try is to use `debug(function)` in the Console, to break on everytime when message is sent. In your case, it could be `debug(ws.send)`.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#debug-function